# Entity framework core can allow to specify two different length for column one for database and other for modal.validation?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Entity framework core can allow to specify two different length of column one for database and other for modal.validation?

Comment: If you are going to validate the size, why does the column need to be a different length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use separate modal for Database and View.

Comment: Can it is possible with same modal ?
My project is already about to complete otherwise i have to change a lot with use of DTO modal and automapper.
I think in EF 6.0 there is attribute maxlenght and stringlength but EF core 1.1 . It's not working :(

Comment: Annotations not so good but the FluentApi works fine for EFC for defining attributes of the field.

Comment: @mvermef: Can you please provide sample for above how i can achive this with fulent api. with multiple lenght for same property one for modal.valid and other for database

Comment: I think I need to see an example what you are attempting

Comment: Can you plese provide same code with fulentapi. which use two lenght one is db and one is for model.validation .